# How to install PHP GD in Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

I want to convert the image in low resolution with GD. I'm working on IBM Server under these speces 
Version: PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (cli) ( NTS )
and I have also comment out the extension from php.ini but can't enabled the GD on php server. 
I Just received this error.

**Run Command:** sudo apt-get install libgd

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libgd

Second Command When I run give this message:

1) packages have unmet dependencies

and after running this command received this:

**Command:** sudo apt-get install libgd-dev

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgd-dev : Depends: libgd3 (= 2.1.1-4ubuntu0.16.04.6) but it is not going to be installed

```
         Depends: libpng-dev

         Depends: libz-dev

         Depends: libjpeg-dev

         Depends: libfreetype6-dev but it is not going to be installed

         Depends: libxpm-dev but it is not going to be installed

         Depends: libx11-dev but it is not going to be installed

         Depends: libxt-dev but it is not going to be installed

         Depends: libfontconfig-dev

         Depends: libvpx-dev but it is not going to be installed

         Depends: libtiff-dev
```

linux-image-virtual : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic but it is not going to be installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Cause of this Problem:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromstring()

Note please anyone tell me the step-by-step command to enable this GD Library on my this Linus machine. 
thanks alot

Comment: First do: `apt-cache search libgd`, because it told you it didn't install libgd.

Comment: You want to resize images or you have problems installing libgd?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/238948/how-to-install-php5-gd-on-ubuntu

Comment: can you try installing `sudo apt-get install libgd-dev`? cause i didn't find libgd package in ubuntu repo

Comment: @selten98 I found this error after hiting this command
sudo apt-get install libgd-dev
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgd-dev : Depends: libgd3 (= 2.1.1-4ubuntu0.16.04.6) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libpng-dev
             Depends: libz-dev
             Depends: libjpeg-dev

Comment: @DevilaN I want to convert like 10MP Picture to 5MP using PHP.

Answer (score 69):

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**For 5.6 PHP**

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd
```

**For 7.0 PHP**

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```

**For 8.0 PHP**

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-gd
```

Comment: You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 linux-image-virtual : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic but it is not going to be installed

 php7.0-gd : Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 is to be installed

             Depends: libgd3 (>= 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed

             Depends: libxpm4 but it is not going to be installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: When I run this command 

sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd 

it gives me above result.

Comment: which version of php do you use ?

Comment: PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (cli) ( NTS )

Comment: try this `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: sudo apt-get -f install php7.0-gd
gives this error ==> 
linux-image-virtual : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic but it is not going to be installed
 php7.0-gd : Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 is to be installed
             Depends: libgd3 (>= 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libxpm4 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Could you please tell me. How to install without package ?

Comment: in case it wasn't obvious, for php7.1 run 
sudo apt-get install php7.1-gd

Comment: sudo apt-get install php7.2-gd

Answer (score 43):

keep it simple...

```
apt-get install php-gd
```

will usually find the correct package and version for your install setup and just install everything nice for you.. did for me

Comment: Does not work for me in Ubunti 21.10, I have PHP 7.4 and when I try this it tries to install something for PHP 8 and fails

Answer (score 7):

For php8.2-gd on ubuntu 22.04 you might want to run

```
sudo apt install libgd3
```

before you install it.

Comment: In my case this was it!

Answer (score 4):

I had an issue where it still wasn't working, even after installing (on ubuntu 20.04):

`sudo apt-get install php-gd`

What finally worked was when I remembered to restart my server, which in my case was:

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: Thats if, you're in apache server if one's in PHP artisan server restart PHP artisan server instead.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue but running `sudo apt-get install php8.1-gd` didn't solve the issue.
I had to run `sudo apt-get install php8.1-gd/bullseye`.

If you running Debian 11,

```
sudo apt-get install php8.1-gd/bullseye
```

If you running Debian 10,

```
sudo apt-get install php8.1-gd/buster
```

If you are using other debian releases, just replace **bullseye** with your debian release name.

You can also search for the extension in the terminal. And install from the result.

```
sudo apt search php8.1-gd
```