# Compiling GD 2.3.3 for existing PHP 7.2.34

Tags: php, gd, amazon-linux-2

The Amazon Linux 2 AMI server has php with version 7.2.34. It contains the GD 2.1 bundled

```
GD Support => enabled
GD Version => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
```

Now I would like to upgrade the GD to version 2.3.3 (https://github.com/libgd/libgd/tree/gd-2.3.3). Is it possible? I'm trying to find documents online but no luck so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install PHP GD in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718896/how-to-install-php-gd-in-ubuntu)

Comment: It's not what I want. GD is installed with php7.2-gd but the version bundled is just 2.1. I want to upgrade it to 2.3.3

Comment: Have you tried re-installing it?

Comment: Yes, it said the latest package is installed "sudo yum install -y php-gd"